# jQuery animate() fail after setTimeout() loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, jquery-animate, settimeout

i'm writing this code (i simplyfied it)

```
function flip(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#block-"+i).css("transform","rotateY(10deg)");
    }, i*200);
}

$("#flip").click(function() {
    for (i=1;i<=6;i++) {
        flip(i);
        $("#block-"+i).delay(i*200+1400).animate({left:100},500);
    }

    $("#text-1").delay(3000).animate({top:200},4000,"swing",function(){
        $("#block-1").animate({top:500},1000);
    });
});
```

i know there are some issues using setTimeout() inside a loop, but the problem is on line

> $("#block-1").animate({top:500},1000);

it's doesn't animate..
when i try take it out from callback, like this

```
function flip(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#block-"+i).css("transform","rotateY(10deg)");
    }, i*200);
}

$("#flip").click(function() {
    for (i=1;i<=6;i++) {
        flip(i);
        $("#block-"+i).delay(i*200+1400).animate({left:100},500);
    }

    $("#text-1").delay(3000).animate({top:200},4000);
    $("#block-1").delay(7000).animate({top:500},1000);
});
```

i't working again, but i have to add delay()
the actual code contain some queued animated element, so i have to calculated each delay and it's so annoying..
is there any fix for this?

Comment: can you post a jsFiddle of this? also, are you open to try out other JS libraries solely made for this and relevant animation purposes without too much overhead?

Comment: this is funny ...i did jsfidle http://jsfiddle.net/deddot/209rdo03/3/ and it works... maybe i cut the code too much..

Comment: **[This](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/yj85c4w2/)** is what I was able to produce, out of interest, using **[TweenMax](http://greensock.com/gsap)**.

Comment: but i'm not try to create that animation.. i just want to take out one block after it get together...my app is finished..  but thanks anyway.. i really appreciate it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahhh. just forget it.. i rewrite the code, fix the problem but still don't know what was wrong before..
actually the new code have another problem.. but that's is another topic..